# Running C code in Termux compiled by clang

Tags: c++, c, clang, termux

I used to compile my code with CppDroid on Android until last night.

After updating the app it began to show `position independent executable` error.

I reinstalled the older version but am still getting the same error.

I know it is a problem with Android 5.0 and above. But then how did CppDroid work till last night? Can anyone give me an answer or any clue?

Termux only provides Clang. Can anyone give me a way to successfully compile C code?

[image: Permission denied error]

[image]

Comment: Have you checked permission and owner of a.out?

Comment: @klutt I just added another image. Please watch yourself. I dont understand the permission symbols.

Comment: It looks like you need to be root to execute it.

Comment: And please don't post images when it is not necessary.

Comment: Android is a bad platform to learn C or C++ development, plain and simple.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart At least it's standard-conforming.

Comment: A Raspberry Pi running Raspbian would be a much better platform.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Agree. At least Raspbian is a full GNU/Linux distro, which is far better than Android.

Comment: Aside from that: each time I see a compiler result belonging to root, a small piece inside me dies.

Comment: I know it's a late answer but check [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/214254/termux-files-permission)

Answer (score 5):

Even though the file mode is `0777`, **Android does not allow files on shared storage to be executed** by mounting with `noexec`.

If you run

```
/system/bin/mount | grep /storage
```

You'll find something like this:

```
/data/media on /storage/emulated type sdcardfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,low_uid=1023,low_gid=1023,gid=9997,multi_user,mask=0007,reserved=100MB)
                                                                ^~~~~~
```

The actual mount point may vary (`/storage/sdcard0`), but it's surely mounted with `noexec`.

You should move the executable to Termux's home directory (or somewhere in an ext4 mountpoint) before trying to execute it. That's what CppDroid does. It only runs executables in internal storage, though the source code may be stored anywhere.

If you want to run in Termux, follow this:

```
$ cp <your-program> ~/a.out
$ chmod 777 ~/a.out
$ ~/a.out
program output
$
```

For the "position independent executable (PIE)" issue, I suggest you clear data for CppDroid. It uses GCC as compiler, which requires `-pie` option to generate PIE executable. If you know what settings are messed up you can also try fixing it by yourself.

The Clang compiler provided by Termux generates PIE executables by default.

Comment: It didn't worked. Again shows same error even after executing "chmod 777 ~/a.out"

Comment: Worked fine here!